# Does a WebSite on Windows Azure has to be stateless when having multiple instances?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, session-state, azure-web-app-service

Please note that I'm talking about Azure WebSites (WAWS), not Azure Web Roles (so it's different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517990/does-a-webrole-on-windows-azure-has-to-be-stateless)).

I've read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsazure/en-us/0ba2c2f6-d5a1-40b6-8d0d-e44b58b65753/will-azure-load-balance-correctly-and-avoid-a-problem-that-app-harbor-had-to-patch-for-me) that Windows Azure uses a sticky load balancing.

Does this mean that azure websites don't need to be stateless ? If I accept that a user lose his session and has to start again on a new server when the first go down (and only in that case), can I keep in-memory sessions ? (instead of using external session state provider)

Please argue by giving some references specific to azure multi-instances websites.

Comment: Comment for downvote ?

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: @Qtx Question updated. However main content of the original question seemed legitimate to me.

Comment: @QtX : off-topic doesn't imply downvoting the question. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199127/should-an-off-topic-question-always-be-downvoted).

Answer (score 0):

See if [How to use ASP.net session state with Windows Azure Web sites](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/session-state-caching/) answers your question fully - it includes discussion on in-process storage of sessions, which is possible but, as you already are aware, fails on multi-instances (Azure or not).

Hth...

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure Websites sounds magic, but basically is an service that route the requests to one or more servers that share the same files using SMB, but these servers have they own memory.

You need use an external session state provider to access the session between different web servers. The sticky load balancing in WAWS allow that subsequent requests will be routed back to the same web server, if the current request server instance is unavailable, the request will be routed to another instance (if you configure more than one, logically), so if you store the session in memory it will not be available in the other servers.

http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/NorthAmerica/2013/WAD-B329/#fbid=